# How to discern whether a 3-year-old's repetitive hand movements are normal or not?

Tags: behavior, pre-schooler, habits

My 3-year-old son has a habit of holding his two hands tightly closed near his mouth and biting teeth so as to show he's excited. He performs this action only when he plays with toys. It comes naturally from him. Even though I hold his hand, he shows his excitement by biting teeth for one or two seconds.

He is also having delay in speech. OT therapist told me that he is completely normal and just expresses his happiness. He responds to his name and is normal in school and church.

Is there any difference between normal repetitive behaviour and autism? And how to reduce it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If he's close enough to neurotypical that your doctor isn't worried, and he is "normal" in church and school, I wouldn't worry about this habit. Autism didn't exist as a diagnosis until I was an adult, and my diagnosis came when I am close to retirement after several successful career in different fields.